# Have item status changes trigger the automatic creation of a new Monday.com group

Tags: project-management, monday.com

I'm working in Monday.com and trying to create an automation where when an item's status changes, a new group is created and is named the same thing as the item.

I'd also be open to other trigger events as long as a new group is created using the item's name as the new group's name in the correct board.